# Pentaho Connect to File Repository Setup

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am trying to connect to the Pentaho Data Integration (Spoon aka PDI) file repository.

Display Name: "testing"

URL: http://localhost:8080/Pentaho

When I click "Finish" it says this:

> We couldn't connect.
>
> Your connection was created, but we tested it and were not able to
> connect to your server. Please check that the server is running.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Theories:

1. What does http://localhost:8080/Pentaho point to? My spoon file is located in "pdi-..." folder. Maybe I need to call this that instead?
2. My 8080 port is enabled, so it can't be that.
3. I disabled my firewall on my private connections, so it can't be that.

Comment: Is PDI and the repository on the same server/pc?    If it isn't then localhost:8080 won't work as localhost is whatever machine you are on.   To test that out go to a browser on the machine with spoon and try to browse to http://localhost:8080/pentaho.   If you get connected then you should be able to connect to the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Pentaho Data Integration has three approaches to store transformation/jobs: Local File Repository, Database Repository (without Pentaho Server is already deprecated), and Pentaho Repository (Recommended) for more detail you can find them [here](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/9.4/Products/Use_a_Pentaho_Repository_in_PDI).

From your question, you created a connection to connect to Pentaho Repository but Pentaho Repository didn't come along with PDI. You need to install Pentaho Server (the underly of Pentaho server also uses a database to store metadata about transformation/jobs by default it uses HSQLDB but you can change it to your desired database). After you've installed and started the server. You will be able to access the main page at `http://localhost:8080/Pentaho` and connect to it in Pentaho Data Integration for more detail about Pentaho Server you can find [here](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/9.4/Setup/Pentaho_installation#r_pentaho_archive_install_overview)